# Detect if an alert, from another VC, is visible

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

Maybe it's a stupid question, but how can you detect if an alert is visible, if that alert belongs to **another** view controller?

I mean, if the alert (call it `myAlert`) belongs to the view controller I am checking, then using `[myAlert isVisible]` will tell you. But if the alert belongs to another view controller (call it `myOtherAlert`), and even worst if you have 10 other view controllers, what do you do? Check for every possible `myOtherViewController.myOtherAlert`? Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you have a (global) variable that every time you open an alert you increase it by 1 and every time you (well, the user) close one (but then, you must go through the delegate to detect the closing) you decrease by 1. Then if the variable is equal to zero, there is no alert active. Sounds to much work, but it is ... language independent.

Answer (score 0):

- One option is wrapping the alert in your own class and adding a class counter for displayed alerts. Then you can always consult the class if any alert is currently visible.
- Maybe you could traverse the subviews of the main window and see if there’s an alert between them. (*This doesn’t really work* – see comments.)
- You can also rethink your UI logic to make it impossible to display multiple alerts at once. I mean, as soon as you display an alert, the user can’t switch to a different view controller. That means that it should be very rare to have an alert on screen together with a view controller that didn’t display it.

Comment: `Maybe you could traverse the subviews of the main window and see if there’s an alert between them.` - this is incorrect, as the alert view  is presented in another `UIWindow` and it won't be anywhere in the view hierarchy of your app's window.

Comment: The first looks more promising. I wish the second could work (that's what I was looking for).

Answer (score 0):

The alert does not belongs to any view or view controller. It's actually shown in another `UIWindow` and I don't think you can find out if it's visible except if you write your own centralized logic to track when an alert is shown and dismissed in your application.

Comment: The alert can be said to “belog” to a view controller in the sense that the controller has displayed it, and maybe also holds a reference to it.

Comment: It can belong to a controller providing presentation context.. and that's not the case for `UIAlertView`. You can presente it from anywhere, anytime - singleton class, the app delegate, some object of yours, view, view controller, etc...

Comment: No. As she states, [myAlert isVisible] will tell you if it's visible or not. Her problem is that this works only for the VC that you open the alert.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your problem is that sometimes your view controllers show alert views even though they are not visible at the moment. In this case there is a simple fix:

```
if ([self.view window]) {
    [alertView show];
}
```

If that's not the case I suggest you look into associative references http://labs.vectorform.com/2011/07/objective-c-associated-objects/

Comment: Nope that's not my problem.